# how does a character array stores the characters as well as count of each character?

Tags: c#, algorithm

Here is my code which has a character array, and character variable.

```
    char[] chArr = new char[1000];
    char ch='A';
    chArr[0]= 'D';
    //chArr[ch] = chArr[ch] + 1; //fails to compile
    chArr[ch]++ ; //works. But how can it store character and its count that too only with ++?
```

In the last line here it increments the count of character A instead of increasing it by one which would be character 'B'.I know t shouldn't behave this way though.But I want to understand how does it store each character and its count here,that too when used only with the ++ operator not by doing chArr[ch] = chArr[ch] + 1;

I understand this because it is the basic for many algorithms around anagrams.

Comment: Why do you have C# *and* C as tags? Their handling of this stuff is very different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do `chArr[ch]++` it increments the value at index `ch` in the array.

Because `chArr[]` contains chars, then this is incrementing the character to be the next one in sequence - so it will convert `'A'` to `'B'`, or `'B'` to `'C'` and so on. For example, if `'A'` has the value 65, then adding one to it will make it 66 which is the character code for `'B'`.

(Your example has you adding 1 to the character with a code of 0 (the nul character) which will produce the character with a code of 1 (the SOH, or "start of header" character), but the principle is the same regardless of the actual character code.)

You *could* in theory use this to count up the number of occurrences of characters (up to a certain limit) since you can treat a character as a counting number with appropriate casting - but that would be a bad way to do it; you shouldn't treat characters as counting numbers.

This doesn't compile:

```
chArr[ch] = chArr[ch] + 1;
```

because `chArr[ch] + 1` is converted to an `int` to do the arithmetic, which then cannot be put back into a char array.

But:

```
chArr[ch]++
```

doesn't convert the char into an int when doing the increment, so it compiles ok.

Note that the following line *will* compile OK, because we are casting the `int` result back to `char` before putting it in the char array:

```
chArr[ch] = (char)(chArr[ch] + 1);
```

Also note that `chArr[ch]++` is equivalent to doing the above, which is why it compiles.

The compiler understands that it needs to treat the result as the same type as the array, so that it appears as if it does the cast for you.

**What do you really want to do?**

If your goal is to count up the number of occurrences of each character, you should instead use an `int` array, since you are interested in counts. What are you trying to accomplish?

**Addendum**

If you really do want to count up the number of occurrences of all the characters in some text, one good way to do it is to use a `Dictionary<char, int>` where each character maps to an integer count. After counting, if a character doesn't occur in the dictionary, it means the character didn't occur in the string.

The code looks like this:

```
string testString = "The owls are not what they seem.";

var counts = new Dictionary<char, int>();

foreach (var ch in testString)
{
    if (!counts.ContainsKey(ch))
        counts.Add(ch, 0);

    ++counts[ch];
}

foreach (var count in counts)
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1} times.", count.Key, count.Value);
```

Comment: Can you make me understand what exactly happens when the statement chArr[ch]++ is executed ? I mean is there a way we can breakdown this statement and understand.Or what does ++ on charArr[ch] does?

Comment: Note that the char 'A' is used as an index inside the array. Thus the OP code increment the value at the slot 65 from 0 to 1.

Comment: Steve, your reply makes sense to me. Though I want to understand it more.

Comment: @krrishna: `chArr[ch]` means “the element at index `ch` of `chArr`”, so the expression `chArr[ch]++` simply means, “Increment the element at index `ch` of `chArr`”.

Comment: @downvoter: Why the downvote? Explaining what's wrong will allow me to fix it!